# Condition on score is not working in my code

Tags: c#, android, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I am making a flappy bird game in unity 3d, but when i put condition on score is greater than 3,Application.LoadLevel() is not working in if statement.
I also put Debug.Log to check if statement, but it also not work.
I have attached code below, you can see it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

static int score = 0;
static Score instance;
Text text;

static public void AddPoint() 
{ 
    if (score > 3) 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("MainMenu");
        if (instance.bird.dead)  return;
    }
    else
    {               
        SceneManager.LoadScene( Application.loadedLevel );
    }

    score++;
}

BirdMovement bird;

void Start() 
{
    instance = this;
    GameObject player_go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

    if(player_go == null) 
    {
        Debug.LogError("Could not find an object with tag 'Player'.");
    }   

    bird = player_go.GetComponent<BirdMovement>();
}

void OnDestroy() 
{
    instance = null;
}

void Awake ()
{
    // Set up the reference.
    text = GetComponent<Text> ();

    // Reset the score.
    score =0;
}

void Update () 
{
    text.text = ""+ score;
}
}
```

I am bit newbie..Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The mistake is in the scope of the if-statement. What your code does is: Increment score if score > 3. The increment has to be outside of the if-clause in order to increment even when the score is not greater than 3

Comment: I think the code is updated now

Comment: click EDIT and format the code properly, with no wasted newlines, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you're never changing the value of `score`. It's `0` by default and because of this `score` is never higher than `3`.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting condition when score is greater than 3 but then you are using another If after condition satisfed. Clear this first and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

`Application.LoadLevel` is depreced

use

```
static public void AddPoint() 
    { 
        if (score > 3) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("WinScreen");
            if (instance.bird.dead)  return;
        }
        else
        {               
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("what_string_name_scene_you_want)");
        }

        score++;
    }
```

Dont forget `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`

What your player has to do to win 1 score? Where `AddPoint()" is called?

**EDIT**

```
static public void AddPoint()
        { 
        // First add score point
        score++;

        // When score better than 3 go to Main Menu
        if (score > 3) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("MainMenu");
        }

        // Another condidion
        if (instance.bird.dead) { 
            return;

        } else {

            SceneManager.LoadScene ("What_level_you_want");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bro SceneManager.LoadScene is not working. SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: You imported, `using UnityEngine.Scene Management`'as I said? Do not FORGET!

Comment: Yes I have imported

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.LoadLevel(<levelNumber>)
```

this method is deprecated, but then also it works now in Unity 5.x versions.
So that you can use that methods like,

```
Application.LoadLevel(0);
```

OR

You can also used SceneManager for switching the scenes.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene ("Your NextScene Name");
```

Plese also implement namespace : `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`

Comment: SceneManager.LoadScene is not working. My unity version is 4.6.1

Comment: Then you have to use,
Application.LoadLevel(0);